# Windows 7 reinstalled, Bitlocker (or not) encryption issue

Tags: windows-7, encryption, bitlocker

I've had to reinstall Windows 7 Ultimate on my PC. I use file encryption for some directories, and I have backups of the .pfx file for the machine. I double clicked the file on the machine and it imported it after following a wizard, but I still can't access files in the encrypted folders.

So I used Encrypt folder in the folder's properties, and not full drive encryption. I don't know if they are both called Bitlocker or not.

After reading all the Bitlocker repair etc articles I don't think it is related, but may be.

So with that all in mind, how do I access the encrypted files given I know the passwords and have the .pfx file?

Comment: Bitlocker works on whole drives only - if you encrypted some directories you are using EFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are two completely different systems. Bitlocker is a newer technology used to encrypt volumes and EFS which is what you are using is used to encrypt on a per file/folder basis.

1. Are you sure you imported them correctly? Run **certmgr.msc** and check under **Personal -> Certificates**
2. If its not there try using **Actions -> All Tasks -> Import** with the certificates folder selected.
3. If it is there, are you sure it is the certificate that was used for the encryption process?
4. What is the error you are given when trying to access an encrypted file?